# On Conflict Do Update not working on partitioned table POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

i am trying to perform an Upsert on a partitioned table with postgres 12.8 .
The query is using CTE to perform the operation with insert followed by update but i get the following error :

```
     [23505] ERROR: duplicate key value violates 
unique constraint "books_20221201_pkey" Detail: 
Key (book_id, book_name)=(1,"abcd") already exists.
 Where: SQL statement "INSERT INTO public.books_20221201 VALUES (NEW.*)"
```

below is the query :

```
WITH bk_temp(book_id, book_name) AS (
            SELECT * FROM ( VALUES
                (1,
                 "abcd"
                )
            ) AS a(book_id, book_name))

            INSERT INTO books
            (book_id,
            book_name)
            (Select t.book_id, t.book_name
             FROM bk_temp t
            ON CONFLICT(book_id, book_name)
            DO Update
            SET book_name="defg");
```

Comment: what's your partition key, can you share the table create syntax...

Comment: @jian partitioning is done on the basis of created_date.

Comment: IHMO. You query is wrong. on conflict is interference with unique constraint/index. Which means (book_id, book_name) should be unique. but you cannot make (book_id, book_name) unique in a partition that partition column i  created_date. Your unique/primary key must include partition column(created_date).  please check manual 5.11.2.3. Limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-partitioning.html) leaves no doubt:

> `INSERT` statements with `ON CONFLICT` clauses are unlikely to work as expected, as the `ON CONFLICT` action is only taken in case of unique violations on the specified target relation, not its child relations.

The partitioned table itself does not contain any data...

Comment: the partitioned table contains the first record which got inserted via Insert query but second time on an update, its giving me this error. Shouldnt it update the record if there's a conflict ? Also, as per postgres, it shouldnt be an issue for PG > 9.5. Is that correct ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The partitioned table does not contain any first record; that will be in a partition of the partitioned table. Yes, it should work, but it doesn't, and this limitation of partitioning is documented.